# how to add position sticky on nested table?

Tags: html, css

I want to add `position: sticky` on the nested table with the subheading but it is not working as expected. the second row is overlapping the first row I tries setting the top for the second row but didn't work.
here is codepen example of what I am trying to do: https://codepen.io/stuxnett/pen/oNYMzGY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that both th lines are stuck to the top per the `top: 0px` attribute. I believe this should do it.

```css
.table tr th {
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid white;

    color:white;
    position:sticky;
    top:33px;
}

.table tr:first-child th {
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `thead` child element of table you can then apply `position: sticky` to that.

```html
<style>
.table_header { position: sticky; top: 0; }
</style>
<table>
 <thead class="table_header">
   <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">Double Row</th>
     <th>Top Row</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Bottom Row</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Anything outside the `thead` will be treated as the `tbody`.
This will also allow you to not change your CSS when adding a third header row etc.